# XML filtering - quick find specific nodes by name + remove parent if value not match

Tags: java, xml

I need a hint regarding a quick finding of specific nodes within the XML and removing the entire parent node (with children) if some of the values don't match the input parameters.

Example, having the XML as shown below:

```
<someparent attr="123" filters="+F1">
    <filter id="F1">
        <width>
            <paper size="a4" val="10" />
            <paper size="a3" val="12" />
        </width>
        <height>
            <paper size="a4" val="10" />
            <paper size="a3" val="12" />
        </height>
    </filter>
</someparent>
```

I should apply some rules:

- like if filters has a value starting with + (+F1) then if parameters match sizes and values, like: a4/10 or a3/12 should not remove the someparent node - any other size should causing the node removal
- if filters has a value starting with - (-F1) then if parameters matching sizes and values, like: a4/10 or a3/12 should remove the someparent node - any other size should leave the node intact

However, I think that may be irrelevant at this point. The most important is quickly finding the filter nodes and removing parent nodes if needed.

Extra notes:

- XPath is way too slow - literally unacceptable, Iterating over every single node is relatively quick - it's currently working like that - however, I'd like to improve that. I'm pretty sure it can be improved.
- it may happen that filter node(s) does not exist in the file at all

My plan is to create some prototypes, however... I'd appreciate any hints that may help me.

EDIT://
Sorry for late reply on that.
So I've ended with StAX - it's rapid and works perfectly for me. Thank you all involved.

Comment: XSLT would be the first choice

Comment: XML parsing is done in document order so the node to keep could be the last one and parsing efficiency could be similar in any case. Or as you said, the node may not exist at all but the whole doc was parsed anyway. Fast or slow is relative on XML. Moreover, finding might not be significant compared to writing the doc after removing a node. All in all, showing just a fragment of the xml without the code used to parse it is not enough to give advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the different built-in parsers are SAX, StAX and DOM (https://rdayala.wordpress.com/dom-vs-sax-parsers/).

- DOM is the slow one (load everything into memory) and is used with XPath.
- SAX is a pain to use.
- [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/api.html) actually has 2 APIs:

  - the iterator API, e.g. XMLEventReader (easier)
  - the cursor API, e.g. XMLStreamReader (more efficient)

You could also try using XSLT, but the built-in one isn't necessarily the most high performing and you may need to pay for a premium one or to use all its features ([streamed processing](https://www.saxonica.com/technology/questions.xml#open)):
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm going to try XMLStreamReader first as the performance is the highest priority for me.

Comment: Apparently the [woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox) implementation of StAX is pretty fast, but you could also try [Aalto XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml).

Answer (score 1):

This xslt 1.0 will do your job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="someparent[@filters='+F1'][not(filter/width[paper[concat(@size,'/',@val)='a4/10'] and paper[concat(@size,'/',@val)='a3/12']])]"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="someparent[@filters='-F1'][(filter/width[paper[concat(@size,'/',@val)='a4/10'] and paper[concat(@size,'/',@val)='a3/12']])]"/>
  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've never thought it could be done that way. Interesting. I'll put that on the list of things to test. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you need to parse the whole document, and the fastest way way to arrive at a solution is to not include the "filtered out" elements in the document building process. Both DOM4J and JDOM are good alternatives for this, since they allow custom document builders that can defer or allow the tree construction based on previously obtained conditions. SAX/StAX is of course also an alternative, but at a lower level and require more infrastructure code to get a result.

Search this site for DOM4J/JDOM and builder, I may already have given the answer ;)

Comment: I'm going to try that. I'll edit my post above when I get some concrete results. Thank you!